# No result returned from LDAP with JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, spring-ldap

I am using spring-ldap and passing this search filter

```
(&(&(cn=*)(objectClass=group))(member=cn=MDMAdmin\, Test,ou=Externe Accounts,ou=Users,ou=Foo-Deutschland,dc=foocompany,dc=int))
```

to method

```
org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(String, String, SearchControls, NameClassPairCallbackHandler)
```

Unfortunately I am getting no result. The same filter works in [LDAP Admin](http://www.ldapadmin.org/).

Following filter works in both:

```
(&(&(cn=*)(objectClass=group))(member=*))
```

Do I need different escaping for spring-ldap? Search base and scope are set properly.

Comment: You don't need two &'s. These filter operators aren't binary: they can take any number of operands. This is the reason prefix notation is used in LDAP filters.

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter:

```
(&(&(cn=*)(objectClass=group))(member=cn=MDMAdmin%2c Test,ou=Externe Accounts,ou=Users,ou=Foo-Deutschland,dc=foocompany,dc=int))
```

**If the distinguished name has a comma character as part of its name**. The following characters must be escaped if they constitute part of a distinguished name: ' ', '"', '#', '+', ',', ';', '<', '=', '>', or ''. See also [RFC4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514).